# Not able to read properties file(Object repository) in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

This is the error I am getting

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest beforetest 
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is my Config reader class to load my property file

```java
public  static void Configreader() {
    try {
        File src = new File("./src/test/resources/config.properties");
        FileInputStream fis = new  FileInputStream(src);
        pro = new Properties();
        pro.load(fis);
        System.out.println("Property class loaded");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception is" +e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

This is my test class where i want to access my webelements

```java
public class LoanDetails extends Configreader {

    static Properties pro;
    WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public  void beforetest() throws Exception { 
        Configreader();
        driver = Browser.GetBrowser();
        System.out.println(" value  is " +pro.getProperty("account_xpath"));
    }
}
```

*i need to access my webelement ("account_xpath") otherwise everything is working*

*i have attached my property file below where i need to acess my webelement (account_xpath)*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are getting Null Pointer Exception because**

1. You have created a new Properties class reference in LoanDetails class again
   and used it.
2. Your Configreader method is never called as there is no testng Annotation in Configreader class so testng will skip that.

**Solution -**

1. Make Configreader method as static
2. Make Properties class obj ref as static
3. Call Configreader method in your before test
4. Property value will work without NullPointerException

Try below code-

```
package com.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Configreader {

    // make property as static
    public static Properties pro;

    // make method as static
    public static void ConfigFileReader() 
      {
             try {
                  File src = new File("./src/test/resources/config.properties");
                  FileInputStream fis = new  FileInputStream(src);
                  pro = new Properties();
                  pro.load(fis);
                  System.out.println("Property class loaded");
              } 
              catch (Exception e) {
                  System.out.println("Exception is" +e.getMessage());
              }
      }
}

package com.example;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;


public class LoanDetails extends Configreader {

    @BeforeTest
    public  void beforetest() throws Exception { 
       // Called this method in before test annotation method  
        ConfigFileReader();    
        //  driver = Browser.GetBrowser();
        System.out.println(pro.getProperty("account_path"));
                driver.findElement(By.xpath(pro.getProperty("account_xpath"))).click();
    }

    @Test
    void testmain() {
        System.out.println("Testng test");
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Could u plz hv a look

Comment: what error you are getting? I have tested this code it was working.

Comment: In your example you have used static Properties pro; in LoanDetails class it should be in Configreader class only. Derived class with use static variable of Parent class...

Make sure you have @Test method in LoanDetails class else testng will skip Before method annotation

Comment: @jino - Please check once again I have updated the code for your reference and also added execution results.

Comment: can u help me in my another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52033851/datadriven-not-working-using-testng-data-provider

Comment: plz have a look

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this error is due to the fact you have declared your `pro` variable in your `LoanDetails` class but not initialized any value. So when you do this -

```
pro.getProperty("account_xpath")
```

it will throw NullPointerException since `pro` is null.

Do one thing, create a get method for account_xpath as well in `Configreader` class, just like you did for "ChromePath" and "ApplicationURL" and access that method.

Code:

```
public class Configreader {

  //your rest of the code
  public  String getAccountXPath()
       {
          String account_xpath = pro.getProperty("account_xpath");
          return account_xpath ;
       }
 }
```

Now, in your `LoanDetails` class, use it as:

```
@BeforeTest
public  void beforetest() throws Exception { 

        driver = Browser.GetBrowser();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(this.getAccountXPath().trim())).click(); 
  }
```

Comment: @Amit still not working, i have updated the code in my question , Could you please check it

Comment: @Amit Could u pllease hv a look

Comment: them.i need to create method for every webelement stored in file??

Comment: @jino you are commenting on the wrong answer. If you want to talk to amit, comment on his answer so that he is notified. On a side not, if his answer is not working, you can try mine.

Comment: then.i need to create method for every webelement stored in file?? –

Comment: @jino yes and that's actually a good way to code , it adds an abstract middle layer.