# Datadriven not working using Testng data provider

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, testng, testng-dataprovider

I am trying to read data from excel using `apache poi` with `testng` data provider but `testng` is skipping my test method.

Below is the error am getting

```
SKIPPED: VerifyLoanDetails
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.seleniumhybrid.utils.ExcelUtil.getTestdata(ExcelUtil.java:62) at com.seleniumdata.zmartano.LoanDetails.getdata(LoanDetails.java:50)
```

Below is my class to read data from excel

```
public class ExcelUtil{

    static Workbook book;
    static Sheet  sheet;
    public static String Testdata_sheet = Constants.path_TestData;



    public static Object  [][] getTestdata(String sheetname) {



        FileInputStream file = null;
        try{
        file = new FileInputStream(Testdata_sheet);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {

            book = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
        }
        catch(InvalidFormatException e ) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }


        sheet = book.getSheet(sheetname);

        Object [][]data = new Object[sheet.getLastRowNum()][sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum()];
        for (int i=0;i<sheet.getLastRowNum();i++) {

            for(int k=0;k<sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();k++) {

                data[i][k]= sheet.getRow(i+1).getCell(k).toString();

            }


        }

        return data;



    }
}
```

below is my test class to acess the data

```
public class LoanDetails extends Configreader{



                  WebDriver driver;     

   @BeforeTest
        public  void beforetest() throws Exception { 

                  driver = Browser.GetBrowser();




       }






    @Test(dataProvider = "getdata")

   public  void VerifyLoanDetails(String username) throws Exception {


    driver.findElement(By.xpath(pro.getProperty("account_xpath"))).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(pro.getProperty("username_id"))).sendKeys(username);


    }


    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] getdata(){

        Object data [][] = ExcelUtil.getTestdata("credentials");


        return data;


    }
}
```

Comment: In what line the exception is thrown? is there any caught exception in `getTestdata()`? I suggest you debug it and see what happens.

Comment: @Guy its showing error in Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.seleniumhybrid.utils.ExcelUtil.getTestdata(ExcelUtil.java:62)
 at com.seleniumdata.zmartano.LoanDetails.getdata(LoanDetails.java:50)

Comment: The exception is somewhere in `getTestdata()`. You need to debug this method and see what happens, or remove all the `try catch` blocks from there to see where is the problem. I bet those blocks mask the real problem, and no much point in them any way, the test can't run without this data anyway, handeling the exception won't help.

Comment: There is no issue with TestNG. Please check with your POI wrapper that you have written. Seems like the poi wrapper didn't bring any data to the data provider. Check on variable initialization and value type in the excel.

Comment: @Amit can U have a look

Comment: @Guy not working , can u have a look

Comment: @jino There isn't something obvious in the code, you will have to debug it. See my previous comment.

Comment: @jino Make sure by retrieving Data Provider return value, Print value of "data" in console. Also, you need to make sure your excel read code whether its retrieves values from excel. First create simple Java program and  check it, and once everything works separately implement it with TestNG annotation.

Comment: @IshitaShah print not working , can u have a look

Comment: You have to print like System.out.println(data);

Comment: @IshitaShah yes i did bt not printing

Comment: @jino So you have problem with your excel read code.

Comment: @IshitaShah ok, let me check it , if you able to find it, plz let me know

Comment: @IshitaShahmy tesng is skipping that test "Verify loan details"